# Split file into multiple according to variable content

Tags: bash, awk, split, grep

I want to split file according to it's content.
My dummy file looks like that:

```
info   info    info    cat
info   info    info    cow
info   info    info    dog
info   info    info    dinosaur 
info   info    info    bat
```

$4 words starts with different letters (C,D,B) - I want to split file into multiples according to the first letter of $4.
Preferable output (3 different files) looks like that:

file_c

```
info   info    info    cat  
info   info    info    cow
```

file_d

```
info   info    info    dog
info   info    info    dinosaur
```

file_b

```
info   info    info    bat
```

Hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: check another example here:http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/01/creating-files-based-upon-line-number.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this oneliner should work:

```
awk '{print $0 > "file_"substr($4,0,1)}' yourfile
```

Comment: Thanks it works! Though I had to replace substr($4,0,1) with substr($4,1,1) - don't know why.

Comment: because "0" is assumed on some awk distribution, to be silently replaced by "1", but it's not the case on all awk out there.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '{name="file_"substr($4,0,1);print >name}' your_file
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp
info   info    info    cat
info   info    info    cow
info   info    info    dog
info   info    info    dinosaur 
info   info    info    bat
> awk '{name="file_"substr($4,0,1);print >name}' temp
> cat file_b
info   info    info    bat
> cat file_c
info   info    info    cat
info   info    info    cow
> cat file_d
info   info    info    dog
info   info    info    dinosaur
```

Comment: Thanks it works! Though I had to replace substr($4,0,1) with substr($4,1,1) - don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ while read a b c d; do echo $a $b $c $d >> file_${d:0:1}; done < dummy.txt
```

Comment: something went wrong. There was only one file_ & it's content was "info   info    info    bat". No file for a or d

Comment: @Poe Strange, it works for me. I tried to change spaces to tabs in the input, but it's still working for me. Are you sure you're on `bash`? Are there backslashes in the real file?

Answer (score 0):

Using Python

```
with open("temp.txt","r") as f:
     for line in f.readlines():
        col = line.split()[3][0]
        filename = "file_"+col
        f2 = open(filename,"a")
        f2.write(line)
f2.close()
```